# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

i am doing one project which will connect to some broker.. it will send a request and get response from server. I need to handle 2 request. one is authentication request and second is approve request. My authentication request is working fine but my approve request is failing with "unauthorized" error. Can someone please guide me whats going wrong. There API says we need to send all data in header with GET as method.Thats the reason I have added as custom headers. Help will be highly appreciated.

```
HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(www.someurl.com);             
webrequest.Headers.Add("Machine", Dns.GetHostName());
webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer" + LoginToken); //This token I get during authentication. i also tried removing the word "bearer" still it is failure.
webrequest.Headers.Add("username", requestList[0].userid);              
webrequest.Headers.Add("messageType", "SS");
webrequest.Headers.Add("customerUniqueTransactionId", requestList[0].locateId);
webrequest.Headers.Add("scageUserId", requestList[0].userid);
webrequest.Headers.Add("accountNumber", requestList[0].account);
webrequest.Headers.Add("security", requestList[0].symbol);
webrequest.Headers.Add("currencyId", "024");
webrequest.Headers.Add("orderQuantity", requestList[0].shares.ToString());
webrequest.Headers.Add("tifInd", "IOC");
webrequest.Headers.Add("repCodeId", "1980");
webrequest.Headers.Add("overrideException", "N");
webrequest.Accept = "application/json";
webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
**webrequest.Method = "GET";**
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
Stream oRespStrm = resp.GetResponseStream();
using (StreamReader oStrmRead = new StreamReader(oRespStrm))
{
   responseFromServer = oStrmRead.ReadToEnd();                 
}
```

Comment: You probably need to capture the cookie returned from authentication and send with the approve request.

Comment: Returning 401 is a decision by the server, so clearly there is some requirement you're not meeting. Are you sure all of those values should be in the headers (it seems kind of strange)?

Comment: "The API says...." well, if it's documented, figure out what you're doing wrong here. I do think the `"bearer" + LoginToken` with no space is likely to be a typo though. Usually it would be `"Bearer " + LoginToken`.

Comment: @jdweng there api says we need to send login token which I receive when I send authentication request. i store this and in approve request is send that value

Comment: my guess: you forgot to add a space: try `"bearer " + LoginToken`

Comment: I notice that the value of the bearer token value does not strictly match [the specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-2) in two ways: 1) "Bearer" is not capitalised 2) there doesn't appear to be the required whitespace between the word "Bearer" and the token.

Comment: @Llama -  i tried Bearer with space in that case I throws Bad request error.

Comment: I'll put this as simply as I can for you: the API you're using has requirements. We don't know those requirements because we don't know what API you're using, we haven't used it, and we don't maintain it. What you're talking about here (401 Unauthorized, 400 Bad Request) are responses that the server is choosing to send to you, based on logic that the maintainers of the API have chosen. You'll have to figure out this one by yourself, or contact the people who maintain the API you're using.

Comment: Bad Request could be a new issue and you solved the first issue by using a capital B.  Bad Request usually means the format of the content in the request is bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for helping me.. I wanted to inform you that it is working now. There were 3 issues.. 1) Bearer with space and token I need to send 2) They were expecting Tif expiry date in request 3) Username was going wrong.. Now this is working.